Can the differential operator be the result of dividing a derivative by the function itself?
I'm confused about some differential calculus in a textbook, and I'm not sure if I'm confused or the book has a mistake.
In Applied Hydrology by Ven Te Chow et al on page 9 we have:
$$k\frac{dQ}{dt} + Q(t) = I(t)$$
so
$$\Omega = \frac{Q(t)}{I(t)} = \frac{1}{1 + kD}$$
Where $D$ is the differential operator $\frac{d}{dt}$.
My question is, how does that last equality work, and how can the differential operator arise? I can get as far as
$$\frac{Q(t)}{I(t)} = \frac{Q(t)}{k\frac{dQ}{dt} + Q(t)} = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{k\frac{dQ}{dt}}{Q(t)}}$$
but I don't see how $\frac{k\frac{dQ}{dt}}{Q(t)} = k\frac{d}{dt}$. In fact a based on this answer, we should have $\frac{k\frac{dQ}{dt}}{Q(t)} = \frac{d}{dt}ln(Q(t))$.
Moreover, does the book's answer even make basic sense by having the differential operator sitting there and not applying to a function?

$(kD+1)Q=I \Rightarrow \frac{Q}{I}=\frac{1}{(kD+1)}$

This (imo horrible) notation does not mean that we are dividing one by $1+kD,.$ In contrast to those applied hydrologists I would have written $(1+kD)^{-1}$ to denote the inverse of that operator.

Thank you both, that clarifies the argument! So the book is correct, but I should be aware of notational ambiguity around operators going forward.
